# How are attributes parsed in Boost.PropertyTree?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Say I have this XML format:

```
<Widget type="SomeWidget" name="foo">
   <Event name="onmouseover">
      dostuff();
   </Event>
</Widget>
```

How do I read the attributes using Boost.PropertyTree?

Comment: Full code example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14010792/438039

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your problem is to get attributes:

> The attributes of an XML element are
>   stored in the subkey . There
>   is one child node per attribute in the
>   attribute node. Existence of the
>    node is not guaranteed or
>   necessary when there are no
>   attributes.

From the doc http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.xml_parser

So just get them from the `<xmlattr>` key in the path.

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I access it exactly? I would really like to see an examle.

Comment: Will `BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("widget.xmlattr")) attributes.insert(std::make_pair(v.first.data(), v.second.data())` do?

Comment: I would love to see a sample that doesn't use BOOST_FOREACH. How about just pure C++ 98? If not, C++ 11 would be okay too, but not ideal. Part of learning a library is seeing the datatypes in use and auto hides the details of learning.

Answer (score 61):

If xml has such content:

```
<mode fullscreen="true">mode xxx</mode>
```

Use boost::property code:

```
get<string>("mode.<xmlattr>.fullscreen")
```

Oh yeah, it's ugly!

Comment: `<mode fullscreen="true">mod xxx</mod>` does not appear to be well-formed xml.