# Parsing XML File with Boost C++

Tags: c++, boost, xml-parsing, boost-propertytree

I have to parse one xml file using boost c++, I have written one test code which is working for this xml.
`a.xml`

```
<a>
    <modules>
        <module>abc</module>
        <module>def</module>
        <module>ghi</module>
    </modules>
</a>
```

Output is coming

```
abc
def
ghi
```

but for this `a.xml` file, my test code is not showing any output, 3 blank lines are coming as output.

```
<a>
    <modules>
        <module value = "abc"/>
        <module value = "def"/>
        <module value = "abc"/>
    </modules>
</a>
```

here is the test code:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    read_xml("a.xml",pt);
    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("a.modules"))
        std::cout<<v.second.data()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My Problem is I am having a large xml file which contains the mixture of patterns from both the files and I have to parse it.
File is b.xml and I have to get message subtag from each tag.

```
<MultiMessage>
    <Message structID="1710" msgID="0" length="50">
        <structure type="AppHeader">
        </structure>
    </Message>
    <Message structID="27057" msgID="27266" length="315">
        <structure type="Container">
            <productID value="166"/>
            <publishTo value="xyz"/>
            <templateID value="97845"/>
            <sendingTime value="1421320622367060444"/>
            <message value="092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK"/>
        </structure>
    </Message>
</MultiMessage>
<MultiMessage>
    <Message structID="1710" msgID="0" length="50">
        <structure type="AppHeader">
        </structure>
    </Message>
    <Message structID="27057" msgID="27266" length="315">
        <structure type="Container">
            <productID value="166"/>
            <publishTo value="xyz"/>
            <templateID value="97845"/>
            <sendingTime value="1421320622367060444"/>
            <message value="092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK"/>
        </structure>
    </Message>
</MultiMessage>
<MultiMessage>
    <Message structID="1710" msgID="0" length="50">
        <structure type="AppHeader">
        </structure>
    </Message>
    <Message structID="27057" msgID="27266" length="315">
        <structure type="Container">
            <productID value="166"/>
            <publishTo value="xyz"/>
            <templateID value="97845"/>
            <sendingTime value="1421320622367060444"/>
            <message value="092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK"/>
        </structure>
    </Message>
</MultiMessage>
```

and output should be :

```
092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK
092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK
092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK
```

Thank You

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.xml_parser):

> The attributes of an XML element are stored in the subkey . There is one child node per attribute in the attribute node. Existence of the  node is not guaranteed or necessary when there are no attributes.

```
<module value = "abc"/>
//One way would be this:
boost::get<std::string>("module.<xmlattr>.value");
```

One more way (untested), which appears to be better:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("a.modules"))
{
    std::cout << v.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.type").data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << v.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.Reference").data() << std::endl;
}
```

One more taken from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010473/parsing-xml-attributes-with-boost)

```
//Parse XML...
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("a.modules"))
{
    const boost::property_tree::ptree &attributes = v.second.get_child("<xmlattr>", boost::property_tree::ptree());
    BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, attributes)
    {
        std::cout << v.first.data() << std::endl;
        std::cout << v.second.data() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is working, But I am having a different file, I edited my question, and I have to parse message field, how to do that.

Comment: @avinashse new questions should be posed as a new question.

Comment: @sehe I posted new question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979067/parse-xml-file-with-c`