# Parse Xml File with C++

Tags: c++, boost, xml-parsing

My Problem is I am having a large xml file which  I have to parse in C++.
File is b.xml and I have to get message subtag from each tag.
My first part of question is:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977851/parsing-xml-file-with-boost-c/27978152#27978152](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977851/parsing-xml-file-with-boost-c/27978152)

```
<MultiMessage>
    <Message structID="1710" msgID="0" length="50">
        <structure type="AppHeader">
        </structure>
    </Message>
    <Message structID="27057" msgID="27266" length="315">
        <structure type="Container">
            <productID value="166"/>
            <publishTo value="xyz"/>
            <templateID value="97845"/>
            <sendingTime value="1421320622367060444"/>
            <message value="092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK"/>
        </structure>
    </Message>
</MultiMessage>
<MultiMessage>
    <Message structID="1710" msgID="0" length="50">
        <structure type="AppHeader">
        </structure>
    </Message>
    <Message structID="27057" msgID="27266" length="315">
        <structure type="Container">
            <productID value="166"/>
            <publishTo value="xyz"/>
            <templateID value="97845"/>
            <sendingTime value="1421320622367060444"/>
            <message value="092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK"/>
        </structure>
    </Message>
</MultiMessage>
<MultiMessage>
    <Message structID="1710" msgID="0" length="50">
        <structure type="AppHeader">
        </structure>
    </Message>
    <Message structID="27057" msgID="27266" length="315">
        <structure type="Container">
            <productID value="166"/>
            <publishTo value="xyz"/>
            <templateID value="97845"/>
            <sendingTime value="1421320622367060444"/>
            <message value="092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK"/>
        </structure>
    </Message>
</MultiMessage>
```

and output should be :

```
092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK
092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK
092374NMKLA90U345N09832LJKN0A9845JHKLASDF09U8426LJAKLJDGF09845U6KLJSDGP89U45LJSDFP9GU4569078LJK
```

Thank You

Regards

Comment: @EdHeal Please check the link which I have give instead of down-voting, I tried to get first part and get help to solve it, Now I asked there second part then I got answer to post this as a new question, that is why I am posting this as a seperate question.

Comment: Question content should be in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using an XML parser to parse this. Doing this kind of query on Property Trees is unwieldy in my experience.

- [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c?lq=1)
- [What is the best open XML parser for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c)

If you use XPath, you can simply do what you want here in a single line. E.g. using PugiXML¹:

```
#include <pugixml.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    doc.load_file("input.xml");

    for (auto& n : doc.select_nodes("//root/MultiMessage/Message/structure/message/@value"))
        std::cout << n.attribute().value() << "\n";
}
```

prints

```
092374nmkla90u345n09832ljkn0a9845jhklasdf09u8426ljakljdgf09845u6kljsdgp89u45ljsdfp9gu4569078ljk
092374nmkla90u345n09832ljkn0a9845jhklasdf09u8426ljakljdgf09845u6kljsdgp89u45ljsdfp9gu4569078ljk
092374nmkla90u345n09832ljkn0a9845jhklasdf09u8426ljakljdgf09845u6kljsdgp89u45ljsdfp9gu4569078ljk
```

Alternatively, use an external tool like `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint --xpath`

¹ which can be used header-only, like boost property-tree

Comment: Thank You for the reply, I downloaded PugiXML Library for linux and I extracted it. I am using eclipse, and I am adding library path to the pugixml path, but eclipse is not able to detect the path, On searching in google, I am getting library settings for visual studio only not for eclipse, please share your words in this regards.

Comment: I use make files. On debian, `apt-get install libpugixml-dev` and then `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lpugixml` does the job. Of course you can download/install manually, in which case the usual flurry of `./configure && make install` or [alternatively including the files into your project and **defining `PUGIXML_HEADER_ONLY`**](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/install.html#manual.install.building.header) should do the job