# c++ boost xml parser ptree.get function -- doesnot accept white space in node name

Tags: c++, xml, boost

Trying to get the content from the xml file using boost xml parser using c++..

**opencv.xml**

```
<opencv_storage>
     <labels type_id="opencv-matrix">
          <data>0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0</data>
     </labels>
</opencv_storage>
```

**C++ Code Snippet**

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::read_xml("opencv.xml", pt);

    std::string m_file = pt.get<std::string>("opencv_storage.labels type_id=\"opencv-matrix\".data");

    std::cout<<"m_file "<<m_file<<std::endl;
```

While executing, the program throws an exception :

```
No such node (opencv_storage.labels type_id="opencv-matrix".data)
```

I doubt, a  white space prevails between labels and type_id

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated, since I am trying to get used to boost.

Comment: The name of the node is `labels`, the `type_id` field is a separate attribute for the node. Just like in HTML where nodes can have attributes. Try just `"opencv_storage.labels.data"`.

Comment: @Joachim It works .. Very simple..

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't. Whitespace in element names is illegal in XML.

What you actually want is attributes: [Parsing XML Attributes with Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010473/parsing-xml-attributes-with-boost)

Or, better yet, you want to use an XML parser, here: [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

---

If somehow you want to use poperty tree (are you sure?) look here:

- [boost::ptree find? or how to access deep arrays? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105711/boostptree-find-or-how-to-access-deep-arrays-c/30125315#30125315)

The enumerate-path function can - obviously - be used for XML too, since it takes a `ptree`