# how to parse XML with ParameterName and ParameterValue using c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm receiving an xml file with credentials and I need to parse it's values in c++11. 
The problem is that I wasn't able to parse this specific xml format (format 1):

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter ParameterName="AccessKey" ParameterValue="ABC"/> 
    <Parameter ParameterName="SecretKey" ParameterValue="XYZ"/> 
</Parameters>
```

I am familiar with boost::property_tree but I was able to parse only the format below (format 2):

```
<Parameters>
    <AccessKey>ABC</AccessKey>
    <SecretKey>XYZ</SecretKey>
</Parameters>
```

Below is the code I used to parse the xml format 2:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

bool getCredentialsfromXml(const std::string &xmlFileName, Credentials& credentials)
{   
    pt::ptree tree;
    pt::read_xml(xmlFileName, tree);

    // 1. AccessKey
    credentials.m_accessKey = tree.get_optional<std::string>("Parameters.AccessKey");

    // 2. SecretKey
    credentials.m_secretKey = tree.get_optional<std::string>("Parameters.SecretKey");

    return true;
}
```

Is there any way to modify my code to parse xml format 1?
or any other way to parse xml format 1 in c++11?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are quite a few XML loaders and parsers available, many of them for C++. You might want to search a little to find a few of those libraries.

Comment: I think you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c). But you could have found this link by yourself :)

Comment: You can try this [Reading structures from XML](https://github.com/incoder1/IO/wiki/Reading-structures-from-XML)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `boost::propery_tree` and have no need to understand (and parse) more XML, maybe the following stackoverflow answer will help you: [How are attributes parsed in Boost.PropertyTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690436/how-are-attributes-parsed-in-boost-propertytree)

Your new format uses XML *attributes* whereas your old format used only XML *elements*. You don't need to know everything. But you need to know the technical terms (like *attribute*), so you can google like I did. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't familiar with the terms attributes and elements. I found the answer in the link you attached. Thanks!